# Como filtrar, com angular, objetos de um JSON por um id que pertence a outro objeto dentro do array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Minha dúvida é como posso filtrar objetos de um array comparando o `id` que está dentro de um "sub-objeto". Tipo:

```
animais [
   {
      id: 34,
      nome: baleia,
      categoria: {
         id: 2,
         nome: mamifero
   },
   {
      id: 23,
      nome: galinha,
      categoria: {
         id: 3,
         nome: oviparo
      }
   }
]
```

Seguindo esse exemplo, gostaria de pegar apenas os animais mamíferos (`id` == 2).

Tenho um serviço que me retorna todos os animais:

```
app.factory('Animais', function($http){
    var animalList,
        obj = {};

    obj = {
        getAnimais:function(callback) {
            if(animalList) {
                callback(animalList);
                return false;
            } 
            else {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://example/api/animais'
                }).success(function(data) {
                    obj.saveAnimais:(data);
                    callback(data);
                })
            }

        },
        saveAnimais:function(data) {
            locaisList = data;
        }
    }

    return obj;
});
```

E meu `controller` está da seguinte forma:

```
app.controller('AnimaisCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $filter, Animais) {
    var myFilter = $filter;

    Animais.getAnimais(function(data) {
        $scope.animais = myFilter('filter')(data.animais, {
            id:$routeParams.id
        });
    });
});
```

Na `view` anterior, o usuário seleciona a categoria. Então ele é redirecionado para a tela de animais que irá mostrar os animais da categoria selecionada.
Alguém me da uma força?

Answer (score 2):

Me corrija se eu estiver errado, mas se entendi corretamente o que você quer é filtrar uma coleção de objetos de acordo com um valor compartilhado entre *controllers*.

Uma das possíveis maneiras é implementando um serviço:

```
app.service('AnimaisSelecaoService', function() {
  var categoria = {};    
  var setCategoria = function(obj) {
      categoria  = obj;
  }    
  var getCategoria = function(){
      return categoria;
  }    
  return {
    setCategoria : setCategoria,
    getCategoria : getCategoria 
  };    
});
```

No controller que coordena a seleção da categoria, injete o novo serviço e utilize o método `AnimaisSelecaoService.setCategoria` para indicar a nova seleção.

Injete o novo serviço no seu *controller* consumidor:

```
app.controller('AnimaisCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $filter, 
                                       Animais, AnimaisSelecaoService) {
    Animais.getAnimais(function(data) {
        $scope.animais = 
            data.filter(function (item) { 
                return item.categoria.id === AnimaisSelecaoService.getCategoria(); 
                });
    });
});
```

Se necessário (por questões de escopo) inclua um `$watch()` para o valor do serviço, ou utilize `$broadcast()` para anunciar a mudança de valor e atualizar sua interface.

Comment: Eu só queria filtrar pelo ID da categoria. É realmente necessário tudo isso? Eu sou bem leio de Angular. :(

Comment: O meu código funciona, sendo que ele ta comparando o `id` dos `animais` e não do objeto `categoria` que está dentro dele.

Comment: @PhellipeLins Eu segui o indicado na sua pergunta - 'gostaria de pegar apenas os animais mamíferos (id == 2)'. Imaginei que 'Categoria' fosse a propriedade necessária.

Comment: Como mencionei, existem várias maneiras. Você pode usar um valor armazenado no $rootScope, que pode ser entendido como um escopo global, assim como referenciar valores armazenados em um escopo-parente. Mas a maneira recomendada é utilizando Services (ou Factories).

Comment: É porque sou tão leigo que até pra perguntar tive dificuldade. Quer que eu reformule? Como seria? Ainda pode me ajudar?

Comment: Dessa forma eu não entendo, preciso da solução em código. Tenho menos de uma semana com AngularJS.

Comment: @PhellipeLins não se preocupe, todos nós começamos do zero; é um prazer ajudar. =) Se puder, reformule sua pergunta *sem focar na tecnologia*.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18626/discussion-between-onosendai-and-phellipe-lins).